# Increase the Terminal width in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

My R Interactive Terminal in Visual Studio Code is too short, cutting-off or wrapping the returned values too early, leading to confusion during data analysis or feature engineering.  Is there any way for me to increase the width of the R Interactive Terminal?

Specifically, I am referring to the Terminal Window that is used to display processed code results from R, Python or any other interpreter:
https://webzest.com/vsc_terminal.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can collapse the sidebar to gain some more space. the toggle sidebar command is under `View/Appearance/Show Side Bar` and the keyboard shortcut is `⌘+B` on macos or `⌃+B` on windows. see attached screen image.

edit: thanks for sharing a screen-print, that helps to explain what you are seeing. sorry i misunderstood... i am wondering if the issue is related to the `R` shell you are running.
you can see in the attached screen images that the `zsh` shell uses all of the space available to the terminal panel.
...also, this is on macos, i have not tried windows but that could be part of it.

can you try some other shells and see if they are affected in the same way?

[image: terminal panel on bottom]

[image: terminal panel moved to right]

Comment: I am referring to this Terminal Window: https://webzest.com/vsc_terminal.png

Comment: i'm sorry @Johnny i don't have the R terminal installed so i completely missed what you were asking about!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new setting in v1.61:

`workbench.action.terminal.sizeToContentWidth`

to toggle wrapping the lines.  Depending on your current terminal width you may or may not get a horizontal scrollbar when you do this but at least you won't get wrapping at some pre-determined too small width.  This command is also available on the terminal tab context menu: `Toggle Size to Content Width`.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686568/automatically-set-optionswidth-to-current-vscode-terminal-width-based-on-a) and answer should help

Basically setting options("width"=200) or any value that works for you