# automatically set `options("width")` to current vscode terminal width based on a DOM attribute?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

If I open a vscode integrated terminal, I can do:

```
$ R
> options("width"=200) # print stuff as wide as i want
```

So I'm wondering if there is any way to automatically re-run a command like `options("width"=<current terminal size>)` based on some DOM attribute whenever I resize the vscode terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to make vanilla R terminal to auto-adjust to vscode R terminal. I recommend that you use [radian](https://github.com/randy3k/radian) which support auto-adjusting width.

Answer (score 0):

use `options(setWidthOnResize=TRUE)`

From the R-documentation: a logical. If set and TRUE, R run in a terminal using a recent readline library will set the width option when the terminal is resized.